# What is causing this TypeError in my Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cryptocurrency, coinmarketcap

I'm trying to call data from Coin Market Cap to a Google sheet via Apps Script. I don't understand the TypeError I'm doing here.

Here is the code:

```
function getCryptoPrice() {
  var sh1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EPS data CMC");
  
  var url="https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=BTC"
  var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest',
  qs: {
    start: 1,
    limit: 5000,
    convert: 'USD'
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': '***********hidden*************'
  },
  json: true,
  gzip: true
};
  
  var httpRequest= UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, requestOptions);
  var getContext= httpRequest.getContentText();
  
  var parseData=JSON.parse(getContext);
  sh1.getRange(1, 2).setValue(parseData.data.BTC.quote.USD.price)
}
```

And the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'USD' of undefined
getCryptoPrice  @ Code.gs:24
```

*Keywords* : google sheet, apps script, coin market cap, quote, latest, V2, api,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because `parseData.data.BTC` is returning an `array`.

**Try changing this to:-**

```
sh1.getRange(1, 2).setValue(parseData.data.BTC.quote.USD.price)
```

**this**

```
sh1.getRange(1, 2).setValue(parseData.data.BTC[0].quote.USD.price)
```

Comment: It worked !
Can you explain (like I'm 5) what it is doing ?

Comment: @NiphitAe Ya. `parseData.data.BTC` is returning data like  this `[{}]` where object is wrapped in an `array` , what you were doing there `parseData.data.BTC.quote` was trying to access  property `quote` of object `BTC`, but to access the property you need an object, as I mentioned it was under an `array`, so you can't access the property `quote`, so what we did there is somewhat removing this `[]` by accessing `0th/first` index of that array `[{}]` and when you left with just `object '{}'` , now you can access `quote`. I hope it makes sense, I am   not good at explaining stuff :P